# Bootstrap modals out of focus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm working on a website and none of my modals seem to be working. I checked all divs and css properties and yet nothing seems to work. [image]

Comment: is there any code over there that you wanna show? also whats means don't working?

Comment: https://github.com/simplykhanh/thoughtloungev2/blob/master/thought_lounge/templates/base.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS:

```
.modal {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```